# is there any issue when creating two temporary tables in one stored procedure

Tags: t-sql

I have written below stored procedure. In which i need to create Two Temporary Tables.
On first temporary table i am taking id's using cursors and then based on some query need to insert in 2nd temporary table. But i get the below error. .
I need some assistance over this situation

> There is already an object named 'TempTable' in the database.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDocumentByTrackID]

@idList nvarchar(50)

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @TrackId INT
```

--Temprary Table 1

```
CREATE TABLE TempTable(
ID INT
)

DECLARE @GetNextRecord cursor
INSERT INTO TempTable SELECT Value from dbo.fn_sqllist_to_table(@idList,';')
```

--Temprary Table 2

```
Create TABLE TracksNameID
(
ID INT,
Name nvarchar(100)
)

SET @GetNextRecord = cursor for select ID from TempTable

open @GetNextRecord
FETCH FROM @GetNextRecord into @TrackId
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TracksNameID
SELECT  ID ,Name FROM  dbo.TestTable 
WHERE   dbo.TestTable.TrackID = @TrackId
END
FETCH FROM @GetNextRecord into @TrackId
DROP TABLE TempTable
END
```

Comment: That isn't a temporary table. And why are you using a cursor for this `insert`?

Comment: oh yes i got my mistake.
Using cursors i am inserting values in the 2nd table by running a query. That's the thought.

Comment: You should just be able to do `INSERT INTO TracksNameID SELECT  ID ,Name FROM  dbo.TestTable t JOIN dbo.fn_sqllist_to_table(@idList,';') f ON t.TrackID = f.Value` and get rid of the need for `#temp` tables or cursors.

Comment: Thanks Martin thank you very much. but my actual query is something thisSELECT   dbo.Documents_CheckList.ID ,dbo.Documents_CheckList.Name
FROM  dbo.Documents_CheckList INNER JOIN dbo.Documents_CheckList_Setting ON dbo.Documents_CheckList.ID = dbo.        Documents_CheckList_Setting.DocID
WHERE     (dbo.Documents_CheckList_Setting.TrackID = @TrackId)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These aren't actually *temporary* tables, you're creating real table objects. If the stored procedure fails somewhere, the tables won't be removed. Better stick with table variables:

```
DECLARE @tableName TABLE (
  id int, ... )
```

and use `@tableName` like a table (which it is). This way everything will be bound to the local scope of the stored procedure.

The drawback of table variables over temporary tables are the lack of clustered indexes and you can't `ALTER` table variables.

Comment: Ohh!! i did that mistake. but even if this is a regular table. Does it means i can't create more than one

Comment: No, the table name must be unique within a database. Otherwise a statement involving a table couldn't be resolved if the table name exists more than one time in the database. But you can create as many tables as you want as long as they don't exist in the database. The same applies to temporary tables and table variables.

Comment: tABLE VARIABLES can HAVE A CLUSTERED INDEX

Comment: Table variables cannot have statistics!

Comment: ouch of course, but they can't have a non-clustered index :-) (if not side effect of primary key or unique constraint)

Comment: They CAN! UNIQUE for example 8-)

Comment: just added it the same second you answered

Answer (score 1):

You creating regular tables, temp table names should begin with #

Try to create #TempTable and #TracksNameID